# What causes duplication of $host value in nginx proxy_pass?

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I need nginx to proxy incoming request to frontend app and add accessed domain name as first path parameter.

```
domain.net/abc?def=xyz -> frontend:3000/domain.net/abc?def=xyz
```

I have this rule defined:

```
location / {
    resolver 127.0.0.11 ipv6=off;

    proxy_pass http://frontend:3000/$host$request_uri$args; // here is proxy/redirect

    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}
```

It works for all paths except for home page. So for request `domain.net` instead of `frontend:3000/domain.net` I get `frontend:3000/domain.net/domain.net` (duplication of $host). Is this error caused by nginx config. How to fix it? And is there better solution to what I am trying to achieve?

Comment: I can't see how `$host` is duplicated. But `$args` is also duplicated, as it's already included in `$request_uri`.

Comment: Perhaps it is not `$host` itself that is duplicated, but somehow its value comes from `$request_uri` when no path parameters are present in initial request?

Comment: It potentially could be something wrong with how frontend app receives request, but the firstmost request handler there already shows duplicate value in incoming request url.